# Starbound crashes on starup

Tags: technical-issues, starbound

If I try to start Starbound it gets past the Chucklefish logo and the crashes. No error messages given. I tried verifying the integrity of the game cache through steam, and then again after deleting the players and universe folders as some other solutions mentioned. It still doesn't work though. How do I fix this?

DxDiag: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07124722608584974881

Chucklefish support forum post: http://community.playstarbound.com/threads/starbound-crashes-on-startup.120457/

Comment: Can you please provide your system specifications?

Comment: @Aventinus I added a link to my DxDiag

Comment: Have you tried [the Chucklefish support forums](http://community.playstarbound.com/forums/support/)? They're more likely to be able to answer this than we are.

Comment: @Michaellogg I have created a post there now.